# Как в Linux создавать сокеты на С++ с STCP?

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, api

Делаю всё по книге "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux: Руководство разработчика". Не компилируется...

```
int main (int arg, char **afs){
 int port=80;
server=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,PPT_STCP);
bzero(&addr,sizeof(&addr));
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(port);//порт
inet_aton("127.0.0.1",&addr.sin_addr);//адрес
if(connected,&addr,sizeof(&addr)) {
    perror("Connect"); 
    send(sd,buffer,msg_len);} 
for(;;){
if(bind(server,&addr,sizeof(&addr))|listen(*server,60!=0)){     
perror("Bind listen");
    }   
    for(;;){    
    int as=assept(server,&addr,sizeof(&addr));
    if(as>0){
        close(as);
        }else{perror("Assept")}
    }
    server.close;
    as.close();
   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: что такое "не компилируется"? какие ошибки? или комп перезагружается?

Comment: `bzero(&addr,sizeof(&addr));` А что такое addr ? он не объявлен. Да и чистить структуру адрес которой передается на размер указателя, а не структуры мягко говоря странно (`sizeof(addr)`) видимо должно быть

Comment: Кинте ссылку на книгу, или Socket API

Comment: Если позволите, предложу альтернативу Вашей книге - Стивенс, "Unix. Разработка сетевых приложений".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой небольшой программе Вы сделали очень много ошибок. Все я перечислять не буду, но для начала:

1. Переменная 'server' не описана. Никак...
2. Вы не включили файл заголовков sys/socket.h
3. Аналогично - sys/types.h
4. ....

Продолжать, или дальше - сами разберётесь ?

Comment: Копаюсь, ошибок прут-пруди.Брал исходники из книги  Скачивал готовые исходники лишбы работало. Везде одни  итеже ошибки.Кинте ссылку на книгу, или Socket API ...  :(

Comment: **Брал исходники из книги** - это не самый лучший вариант! Во первых - опечатки! Ну и, самое главное, в книги приводятся КУСКИ кода. В начале книги написано, что исходные тексты всех примеров находятся на сайте сопровождения этой книги.  Вот только нет ссылки на этот самый сайт! Более того, даже нет названия на английском языке, что бы поискать самому... Короче: ищите этот сайт, скачивайте с него сорцы - вот они будут работать!

Comment: Насколько я понял, по английски эта книга называется так: Linux Socket Programming, Sean Walton

Ищите и обрящите! :-)